# Sharepoint 2013 throws SPException on the testing server

Tags: sharepoint

I have this very weird problem.

**This is the code:**

```
SPList list = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/List1");
```

This line of code throws a SPException with absolutely no useful info in it.

**What I tried:**

-List1 is not actually a list but a Document library(not that it maters). I tought Sharepoint might be acting funny and used SPDocumentLibrary instead if SPList. It didn't work.

-I then tought that there might be some access issues and ran this code with ElevatedPrivileges - same story.

-I also tried different ways to get the url to the list - did not fix it.

**The weird part**: This code works perfectly on my virtual machine. The problem occured when I ran the code on the test server.

**EDIT 1**

There is no problem in the URL and the list is there. I can see it when I run `web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/List1")` in the Watch window. Everything looks fine but the exception is still thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the URL you are building is correct? Also, document libraries usually do not reside under the `Lists/` folder.

Comment: Check the URL - does the list reside at the same location on the test server? Try PowerShell on the test server, you can use almost the same code there and see if you get further with it. Try other methods to get the list (e.g. by title and with `TryGetList`)

Comment: The URL is correct when I am in debug mode and I run the command web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/List1") in the Watch it shows the list and everything seems fine until the above line

Comment: Are your alternate access mappings configured correctly?

Comment: Just checked - no problems there as far as i know